# Regex to Capture Each Line to Unique Capture Group, Where Number of Lines Varies, and Some Data may be Missing

Tags: php, regex

I’m looking for a regex expression that will capture each line (NOT including the line title colon and the space) to a separate Group. I'm using this regex within the Mac Application Keyboard Maestro.

Here's what I have: https://regex101.com/r/pxVzPM/1

My current regex captures the entire line but I recently decided to add the 'name' of the data like "Prefix: " and so I only want to capture the data itself. I tried changing the capture so that it ignores everything before the data I want like this:

```
\R?\h*:\ ((?:.+)?)
```

But when I repeat this, the regex no longer works.

Also, it would be great to have this as a repeating capture group if at all possible, instead of having to copy the code 11 times.

Caveats:

1. Sometimes, the field data may be blank like ‘Start: ‘ - see below. The ‘Start: ‘ would be there, but the actual ‘Start’ data may not. But any of these data 'may' be blank.
2. I need a regex that will work for data with a minimum of say 4 or 5 lines, up to 'as many lines as are present'. Most likely this will be less than 20 total lines.
3. The capture data could be 'anything' from text to numbers to a colon etc.

Here is the data that I'm searching:

```
Prefix: 123
Name: Testing
File: 12345
Description: This field
Duration: 01:32
Start: 
Volume: 200
Tempo: 120BPM
Referencing: Another Track
Original: This One
Notes: This is a test project
```

So I’m trying to capture this:

```
123
Testing
12345
This Field
…etc.
```

Into Capture Groups:

Group 1 would be:
123

Group 2 would be:
Testing

and so on...

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the post.

Comment: If you want to have multiple capturing groups you would have to add them all. If you use php you might use `^\h*[^\s:]+:\h*\K.*` to get the matches only See https://regex101.com/r/4hlTGg/1

Comment: `^\h*[^\s:]+:\h*\K.*` @Thefourthbird thanks, this works great for the matches but I'm having trouble determining how to repeat it for multiple capture groups.

Comment: If you want multiple capturing groups like number 1, 2, 3 etc  you would have to add them.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, right `^\h*[^\s:]+:\h*(\K.*)` this gives me Group 1, but duplicating the regex for a Group 2, 3 etc. is not working. Thanks!

Comment: It would look like https://regex101.com/r/Bo0iWR/1/ You could make them optional `(?:\R\h*[^\s:]+:\h*(.*))?` if you don't know the number of groups.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, https://regex101.com/r/Bo0iWR/2 is limited to these exactly 11 lines. Is there a way to allow for 'any number of lines'? Like in my original regex? That is, there may be only a few lines, but there may also be maybe up to 15 lines.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. You could make them optional but that is not a pretty sight https://regex101.com/r/Dnujx3/1

Answer (score 0):

What about `:\s*(.*)`?

This will start looking for a `colon`, followed by an optional `whitespace` and captures everything after the whitespace till the end of the line in a group.

You can look at the results of your test-data here:
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pxVzPM/2)

EDIT:
For included blank data you can use this one: `:(.*)` but then you have to trim all results to remove the leading whitespace

Comment: Hi thank you but I'm having trouble replicating this for multiple groups. And it doesn't take any 'blank' data in to consideration - like "Start: "